# Branching model as we move to continuous integration

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

The goal is to be able to automate the build, so that whenever a developer checks their code in (or merge to a particular branch that has this trigger setup), the code should ship to the dev and QA environment.  Pushing to production I imagine will require some manual involvement.

Note:  This is a legacy application so we don't have control over how many things are setup.
Team size is about 10 developers.

Branching Strategy I have so far:

```
[1]Developer branch
[2]Main (Production) branch
```

When a developer is creating a new feature, they branch of the developer branch like: `dev_branch_feature_xyz`

When they want to push to the DEV or QA site for testing, they merge into the developer branch which will trigger TeamCity to first pull any changes from the Main branch, then compile etc. and then push to the DEV and QA servers.

Now if QA has signed off on a feature and it is ready for production, how will be pull the correct code to the Main branch and push the changes to our UAT environment and then production?

For example, feature#1 might get merged into dev, then feature#2, then a programmer might merge a bug fix for feature#1 again into dev, and maybe another merge for feature#2, so the DEV branch now has parts of feature#1 and feature#2, and there is no way to cherry pick the code to push to the MAIN branch now (if say feature#1 is ready for production).

**Also, is this a sound strategy?  Any issues that you guys see?**

*Remember:  Currently much of this will be manual (merging, pushing to servers) but the goal is to move to using TeamCity so I need to setup the branching strategy now.*